# Discordant vs controversial vs non-concurring

Tags: meaning, differences

Do these three words mean the same thing?

From my understanding, **discordant** means not agreeing or out of tune. This is similar to **non-concurring** (as concurring would mean agreeing on something). Also, **controversial** means something which gives rise to disagreement.

How do I understand the subtle difference in meaning when the wors are so similar?

Answer (score 6):

*Controversial* is the adjective form of *controversy*. And [*controversy*](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=controversy&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=YXceUJ76DKG26wHftYHwAg&sqi=2&ved=0CFgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=fd6c06992f8070d8&biw=1345&bih=559) is defined as "disagreement, typically when prolonged, public, and heated." Therefore something that is *controversial* is "of, producing, or marked by controversy." It has aspects of dividing public opinion over a period of time, often heatedly so.

[*Discordant*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discordant) means "not being in accord; conflicting." And one definition of [*accord*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accord) is "a settlement or compromise of conflicting opinions." So *discordant* has more of the connotation of being disharmonious, being contrary, clashing with others on purpose.

[*Nonconcur*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonconcur) is defined as "to refuse or fail to concur." And [*concur*](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=concur&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=xHgeUPiUOqLV0QHP7YG4Dw&sqi=2&ved=0CFAQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=fd6c06992f8070d8&biw=1345&bih=559) is defined as "be of the same opinion, agree; agree with a decision, opinion, or finding." So *nonconcurring* can be a quiet, nonpublic disagreement with something. It doesn't have to be one side or the other, it could be that there are several nonconcurring opinions. This is the word used sometimes when a Supreme Court justice has a dissenting opinion. One of Merriam-Webster's sample sentences is: *The one nonconcurring judge in the case issued his own opinion.*

You are correct that the meanings are similar, and it will depend on the context in which the word is used but, based on their definitions, I think *controversial* has a public and prolonged element to it, *discordant* has an intentional element to it, and *nonconcurring* has a thoughtful, respectful connotation.

Comment: One thing (topic, opinion, action, &c) can be 'controversial' - subject to argument - but it takes two things to be 'discordant' - even if everyone ignores the discord and there's no actual argument! . . . And in USC usage, a 'concurring opinion' is one which concurs in the decision but differs on the reasoning. I've never seen 'non-concurring opinion' for 'dissent', but that's what it would be.